# How can I extract to PDF without the reviews?

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, pdf, microsoft-word-2011

I have a word document that contains reviews from many people, as you know the reviews are these things that can be added and appear on the left side of your document.

My problem is that when I extract my word document to a PDF, i get the reviews on the PDF as well

Please look how ugly it is:

[image]

That was the cover and look at the left side, this panel is for reviews:

[image]

and here you can see the reviews (sorry I hid the text because it is private).

I am working on Word 2011 on a Mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Word 2016, however the process should be similar for Word 2011

1. Go to the `Review` tab
2. Change the `Tracking` to `No Markup`
3. Export your PDF
4. You can re-enable tracking marking after this if you wish.

[image]

A screenshot from Word 2011 For Mac:

[image]

Edit- It appears the options in Word 2011 are `Final Showing Markup`, `Final`, `Original Showing Markup` and `Original`. The equivalent would be `Final`.

Comment: under tracking, i have `Final showing markup`, `final`, `original showing markup`, and `original` i don't see the options you have mentioned

Comment: Ah, they must have changed it. Use `Final`, as you want all the changes, but not the markup.